# Import data in iOS App from MySQL Database

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to read a row from my MYSQL Database and turn it into a String Array in my app.

My PHP code produces the following output in JSON:

```
[{
    "Kategorie": "Externals"
}, {
    "Kategorie": "Home"
}, {
    "Kategorie": "Lehrer"
}, {
    "Kategorie": "Oeffnungszeiten"
}, {
    "Kategorie": "Orientierung"
}, {
    "Kategorie": "Schulleitung"
}]
```

The function in my App (using Xcode 8 and Swift 3):

```
func get()
{
    do{
        let dburl = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/index.php")
        let dbdata = try Data(contentsOf: dburl!)
                   
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dbdata, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]
        
        if let arrJSON = json["Kategorie"]
        {
            for indexx in 0...arrJSON.count-1
            {
                let aObject = arrJSON[indexx] 
                TableArray.append(aObject as! String)
            }
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError{
        print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

It doesn't show me any errors or something like that. When I simulate it the app freezes at the line where I try the serialization.

And the obvious question is: What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dbdata, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]
```

Your data is an array of `[String:Any]` dictionaries. But you are casting it to `[String:AnyObject]`

Change that line to:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dbdata, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [[String:Any]]
```

Of course, you'll have to modify the rest of the data parsing code after that as well since you will need to loop through the array to get values from each dictionary instance.